# Material-UI: How to set height of a div equal to appBar's height

Tags: material-ui

I need to set the Drawer padding-top equal to the appBar height.

I can reference the appBar through getMuiTheme function, but I am not sure how to pass this down my child Drawer?

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <div style= {{"paddingTop": "64px", "minHeight": "400px", "paddingLeft": "256px"}}>
                <div style = {{"margin": "48px 72px", "height": "600px"}}>
                    My component is here

                     {this.props.children}
                </div>

            </div>
            <Menu/>

        </div>
    );
}
```

I need to reference the appBar's height dynamically so whenever I change my appBar height I don't have to worry about the paddingTop here anymore.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [React-Measure](https://github.com/souporserious/react-measure) to get the height of the appBar and save it in the component's state. You can use that height to set the height of the div.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.